# How to filter out the last days of every year with SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with all days (1-31) of 2021 and 2022.
I want to filter out the last days (24.12 - 31.12) in every year.

I tried following:

```
SELECT DATE_column
FROM TABLE_A
WHERE CONCAT(DATEPART(dd,DATE_column), DATEPART(mm,DATE_column)) not in (2412, 2512,2612,2712,2812,2912,3012, 3112 )
```

Yes it does working. But I wonder whetever there are a more simple method.

Comment: Something like _where datepart >= 24 and yearpart in (2021, 2022)_.

Comment: `JOIN` to a calendar table, and then just have `WHERE CalendarYear IN (2021,2022) AND CalendarMonth = 12 AND CalendarDay >= 24`?

Comment: Do you mean December 24 - 31 only? (Or every month?)

Comment: @jarlh yes you right. Only in Decembers

Comment: To remove these dates you can use `AND/OR` logic. This would work: `WHERE NOT (DATEPART(MONTH, date) = 12 AND DATEPART(DAY, date) >= 24)`, or applying de-morgan's law, you can rewrite as `WHERE DATEPART(MONTH, date) <> 12 OR DATEPART(DAY, date) < 24`. Either would work

Comment: WHERE NOT OR WHERE 1 = 1 AND NOT is what I was looking for. This is great

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT DATE_column FROM TABLE_A
WHERE (MONTH(DATE_column) = 12 AND DAY(DATE_column) < 24) or MONTH(DATE_column) < 12
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
DELETE FROM your_table
WHERE MONTH(DATE_column) = 12 AND DAY(DATE_column) >= 24
```

Comment: I mean how not SELECT the last Days in December

Comment: Just wrap the both expression in a `NOT`, @PeterXO

Comment: @PeterXO WHERE MONTH(DATE_column) != 12 OR (MONTH(DATE_column) = 12 AND DAY(DATE_column) < 24)

Comment: `where month < 12 or day < 24`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE (YEAR(date_column) = 2021 AND MONTH(date_column) != 12) OR (YEAR(date_column) = 2022 AND MONTH(date_column) != 12) OR (MONTH(date_column) = 12 AND DAY(date_column) < 24)
```

Note: "date_column" should be replaced by actual date column name in your table.